# Differentiate then solve or vice versa. Why is there a difference?

Tags: derivatives

The other day I stumbled upon the following problem.

> Start with a rectangular piece of card an integer number wide, by an
>   integer number long, with one of those values being prime.  Then cut
>   four identical squares from each corner of the card. Fold up the four
>   "flaps" to create an open topped box, where the corners have been cut
>   in such a way to allow the maximum volume possible for the box. Once
>   the box is made, it turns out that the base length is 4 times larger
>   than the base width.
>
> What are the dimensions of the original card?

I did solve the problem. But I still have a question. Let $L$ and $W$ be the length and width of the original paper and $x$ the length of the cut-off square. The volume of the box is a function $V(L, W, x)$.

$$V(L,W,x) = x(L-2x)(W-2x)\tag{1}$$

We also have that

$$L-2x = 4(W-2x)\tag{2}$$

I solved the problem by first finding the derivative of $V(L,W,x)$ with respect to $x$ and then making use of the second formula, finding a relationship between $W$ and $L$, and considering they're both whole and one of them is prime, I got the correct answers for $W$ and $L$ ($W = 3$, $L = 8$).

However, if I first substituted the second formula into $V(L,W,x)$ and then differentiate, I arrived at wrong results. I mean, if I first rewrite $V$ as

$$V(W,x) = 4x(W-2x)^2$$

Differentiate, find $x$ expressed with $W$, and substitute in $(2)$, I get wrong results. Why?

Comment: you use very strange notation

Comment: @AdiDani: I'm new to this SE. I'll improve over time :)

Comment: This is a good question.  It would have been nice to explicitly show your results for each calculation so others don't have to reproduce the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes because in the first method, you are considering $L$ and $W$ to be fixed, then finding $x$ to maximize the volume.  In the second, $L$ varies with $x$ to maintain the relationship $L-2x=4(W-2x)$ and $x$ is chosen to maximize the volume.  At the optimum for this one, we have $x=\frac W6, L=3W$

Comment: Yeah, seems you're right! Thanks